# Error while executing if else condition in Powershell

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to execute the if & else code but unable to pass through the condition

```
{
    if(($ENV_TYPE = 'Dev') && ($REGION_CODE = 'eus2'))
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Both the `env_type` and `region_code` values are getting from env variables

I get this error:

> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($ENV_TYPE -eq 'Dev' -And $REGION_CODE -eq 'eus2'){

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: tried the above if condition but it's not working it is directly going into else condition even after passing the accurate variables

Comment: Are you sure the values of the two variables actually are 'Dev' and 'eus2'? 

Try running the script below.  The script should echo the 'Both Match' string

`$ENV_TYPE = 'Dev'
$REGION_CODE = 'eus2'

if ($ENV_TYPE -eq 'Dev' -And $REGION_CODE -eq 'eus2'){
    echo 'Both Match'
}
else{
    echo 'Both Do Not Match'
}`